# What is the probability that the Rectangle lies entirely inside the Circle?

Tags: probability, geometry, solution-verification, circles, rectangles

> **QUESTION:** Point $A$ is chosen randomly from the circumference of the unit circle, while point $B$ is chosen randomly in the interior. A rectangle is then constructed using $A, B$ as opposite vertices, with sides parallel or perpendicular to the coordinate axes. What is the probability that the rectangle lies entirely inside the circle?

---

**MY ANSWER:** Here's what I have done..

Without loss of generality, assume that the circle is centered at the origin ($O$). Now, consider the point $A$ in the first quadrant and we will find out in which region point $B$ has to lie in order to satisfy the given condition..
Clearly, the condition is satisfied if $B$ lies anywhere inside the area of the rectangle formed by the points $A$, it's reflection on the $x$ and $y$ axes and reflection about the origin.

Let $\vec{OA}$ make an angle of $\theta$ with the positive direction of the $x$ axis. By symmetry, one side of the above proposed rectangle is $2\cos \theta$ (one which is parallel to the $x$ axis) and the other is $2\sin \theta$ (that which is parallel to $y$ axis).

Therefore the area of the rectangle when $\vec{OA}$ makes an angle of $\theta$ with the positive direction of the $x$ axis is $$A_{\theta}=2\sin \theta . 2 \cos \theta$$
$$A_{\theta}=2 \sin {2 \theta}$$

This is the feasible region for point $B$. Obviously, the total area to choose from is nothing but the total area of the circle and that is $\pi \times 1^2 = \pi$

Hence, the probability in this case becomes $$P_{\theta}=\frac{2 \sin 2 \theta}\pi$$

Now, as we have considered the first quadrant, $\theta$ can vary from $0^{\circ}$ to $90^{\circ}$. We simply need to integrate $P_{\theta}$ from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}2$. That's what we do -

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{{\pi}}2} P_{\theta} \text{ }d \theta$$
$$= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}  \frac{2 \sin 2 \theta}\pi d \theta $$
$$=\frac{2}\pi \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2} \sin 2 \theta \text{ } d \theta $$
$$=\frac{2}\pi$$

Now this is the required probability when $A$ lies in the first quadrant. Clearly, according to the symmetry of the problem the probability will be same for all the four quadrants.. And since $A$ can lie in any one of the four quadrants, the answer must simply be

$$P_{\text{total}}=\frac{2}\pi \times 4$$
$$\therefore P_{\text{total}} = \frac{8}\pi$$

$\big($ or one may even think in this way

$A$ can lie either in the $1^{\text{st}}$ quadrant OR $2^{\text{nd}}$ OR $3^{\text{rd}}$ OR $4^{\text{th}}$

$\therefore P_{\text{total}} = \frac{2}\pi +\frac{2}\pi +\frac{2}\pi +\frac{2}\pi = \frac{8}\pi$  $\big)$

Wait........ What!!??

Probability greater than one!!... Reasons?

Either we have just (unknowingly though) made a grand discovery!

Or, we have just made a mistake :P..

And I know that the later case is more believable (hehe :') )... But I cannot find any mistake in this..

Can anyone help me out ?

Thank you so much for your kind support..

Comment: Of course, the probability cannot exceed $1$. Maybe, you "counted" the rectangulars mutltiple times ?

Comment: Didn't you forget to divide $\int P_{\theta}\, \mathrm{d}\theta$ by something? Imagine for a second that $P_{\theta}=1$, but $\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2} P_{\theta}\, \mathrm{d}\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}>1$.

Comment: @Alexey Burdin I realized that.. But I cannot understand with what should I divide....

Answer (score 3):

Your $P_\theta$ is actually a conditional probability. More precisely if we let $C$ be the event that the rectangle is contained in the circle, then
$$P_\theta = \mathbb{P}(C \: | \: A=\theta),$$
where we just represent $A$ by its angle rather than its coordinates. To find $\mathbb{P}(C)$ we use the law of total probability
$$\mathbb{P}(C) = \int_0^{2\pi} \mathbb{P}(C \: | \: A=\theta) f_A(\theta) \: d\theta,$$
where $f_A$ is the density function of the angle, which is $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ assuming a uniform distribution. So using the same symmetry arguments that you did, we find that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi} \mathbb{P}(C \: | \: A=\theta) f_A(\theta) \: d\theta &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot4\cdot \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2 \sin(2\theta)}{\pi} \: d\theta \\
&= \frac{4}{\pi^2}
\end{align*}
which is a valid probability.

Comment: [+1]. Result confirmed by a simulation I just made. Just a little non-mathematical remark: "it's" $\to$ "its".

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the typo.

Comment: I didn't get the density function properly.. Can you please explain that a bit?

Comment: If you do not know what a probability density function (or PDF) is, then i recommend reading this: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_1_1_pdf.php . 
Saying that the angle has a uniform distribution is a way of saying that all angles are equally likely and thus the PDF must be constant. Also a PDF must integrate to 1, so $$\int_0^{2\pi} f_A(\theta) d\theta = 1,$$ but if $f_A$ is constant, then $f_A(\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}$.

Comment: If you are not familiar with the law of total probability, then i recommend understanding the discrete version first (see this https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_4_2_total_probability.php ). And then notice that the version i used is just a continuous analogue where summation is replaced with integration and probabilities replaced by a probability density function.